# If statement in formula field

Tags: formula, custom-field, formula-field

I am trying to develop a formula to determinate current days until the end of a campaign.

For that i have the following fields

- Start Date
- End Date
- Days from Today to End Date

The code that i am implementing and its not working correctly is.

```
IF( Now()  >= EndDate , 0, EndDate -  TODAY())
```

So basically what i want to accomplish is. If today is equal to the end day of the campaign return 0 else return the remaining days.

Comment: You say it's not working correctly, but what exactly is it doing now?

Comment: keeping this number value EndDate -  TODAY()

Comment: Do you mean it always shows the result of EndDate - TODAY()?

Comment: I think i kinda know the mistake. It gives false because its false :D
What i want to accomplish is if Now is equal or bigger than End Date...
I tried that at this moment but it gives error

Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '>'. Expected DateTime, received Date

Comment: I thought so too, please try the answer I added. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should use TODAY() instead of NOW(). NOW() returns a datetime while TODAY() returns a date. This means you can't compare NOW() to EndDate.

Another problem is that it only shows 0 if the EndDate is **exactly** equal to TODAY(). This is only one day. You want to check whether EndDate is greater than TODAY():

> IF( TODAY() > EndDate, 0, EndDate - TODAY() )

Comment: I still get this error:

Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'DATE()'. Expected 3, received 0

Comment: Woops, please try my changed answer :-)

Comment: Works like a charm. I rushed with my question It wasn't that hard at the end. 

Thanks @Koen

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `DATE()` formula. Because `NOW()` returns a `DateTime` value. Comparing a `DateTime` with a `Date` will always return `false`. Try using `DATE(NOW())`